# VB6 EXE with argument working in CMD file, but not in C# code

Tags: c#, com, vb6, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have a VB6 EXE which I want to trigger through C# code as shown below. After this code execution, I can see the EXE has been started in taskmanager, and got finished after sometime.

I deploy the code in IIS Server. Start Browsing the site and click on the button of c# code which starts the VB6SOME.exe. The Exe started but never got completed (Taskmanager is showing the VB6SOME.exe for user NETWORK Service).

```
 prcstrinfo.FileName = "VB6SOME.exe";
prcstrinfo.Arguments = "USERID,PASSWORD," + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();          
Process proc = Process.Start(prcstrinfo);
```

Also, I tried to call the VB6SOME.exe through CMD passing all necessary arguments. It got started and finished correctly. (I also monitored the TaskManager and I saw that it started as MY ID not as Network Service). Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: You might try capturing the exit code of the application and see if that gives you any insight. Are you able to run the exe manually (with the same arguments) on the server?

Comment: Yes - I am able to run exe through CMD in Server with out any issue. Only difference is When I ran through CMD file, user name is showing My ID, but when it ran through C#, the user name is showing as NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: Well there's your answer then...!

Answer (score 0):

> **Registry Redirector**
>
> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of key portions of the registry on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit registry calls to each logical registry view and maps them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit Windows.
>
> Redirection is enabled for the following registry keys:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software

From Windows SDK 64 Bit Development Guide